# Excel Override Default Hyperlink Format for a specific range in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, formatting

I have the situation where I have a column in Excel with inserted symbols (wingdings) that will have hyperlinks to external documents inserted. The issue I'm having is that when the hyperlink is inserted into the cell, the default hyperlink formatting is applied which removes the wingding font from the cell and replaces it with the default font which results in the icon being replaced with a number.

I'm aware that hyperlink styles can changed through the cell styles ribbon, however there doesn't seem to be a way of applying different hyperlink styles to a specific range, and I don't want the hyperlink styles for the whole workbook to default to wingdings as the font.

Is there a simple way of applying a font style to a cell when a hyperlink is inserted (and therefore overriding the default hyperlink style) using VBA, and conversely applying a different style if a hyperlink is removed?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcoXf.png)

I want the cell icon to be grey when there isn't a hyperlink inserted, and black when there is a hyperlink inserted.

Any help with the matter would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This UDF will identify if a Cell or Range contains Hyperlink objects, and can then be used with Conditional Formatting:

```
Public Function IsHyperlink(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    'Quick Win - look for Hyperlink Object
    IsHyperlink = (Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0)
    'Check if Excel can convert Target to a Hyperlink
    'Important because the worksheet recalculates BEFORE that happens
    If Not IsHyperlink Then
        IsHyperlink = (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Target, "www.*") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Target, "ftp://*") _
            + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Target, "http://*") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Target, "https://*")) > 0
    End If
    'Check for HYPERLINK() formula
    If (Target.HasFormula Or IsNull(Target.HasFormula)) And Not IsHyperlink Then
        Dim rCell As Range, sFormula As String, aFormula() As String, lStart As Long, lEnd As Long
        For Each rCell In Target.Cells
            If rCell.HasFormula Then
                sFormula = rCell.Formula
                'Remove any text
                While Len(sFormula) > Len(Replace(sFormula, Chr(34), "")) + 1
                    lStart = InStr(sFormula, Chr(34))
                    lEnd = InStr(lStart + 1, sFormula, Chr(34))
                    sFormula = Left(sFormula, lStart - 1) & Mid(sFormula, lEnd + 1)
                Wend
                'Replace "+", "-", "*", "/", "%"
                sFormula = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(sFormula, "+", ","), "-", ","), "*", ","), "/", ","), "%", ",")
                'Replace "=", "(", ")", " "
                sFormula = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(sFormula, "=", ","), "(", ","), ")", ","), " ", ",")
                'Search for "HYPERLINK"
                If InStr(UCase(sFormula & ","), ",HYPERLINK,") Then
                    IsHyperlink = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
End Function
```

<s>Currently, it does not detect Hyperlinks embedded through the `HYPERLINK` formula (e.g. `=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/", "Visit Stack Overflow!")`)</s> **Now it does!**

N.B. Due to event order, Excel will recalculate UDFs *before* it converts any URLs typed into cells into Hyperlinks.  As such, I have included a line to this that will also find cells that Excel *can* convert - otherwise you would need an additional calculation to occur to get the result

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't seem to automatically update when a hyperlink is added or removed. I'm guessing it's because the cell value doesn't change when a hyperlink is inserted? Is there any way to get it to automatically update?

Comment: @mrshl The [`Application.Volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile) *should* be doing exactly that...

Comment: @mrshl Found the issue. When you type a URL, then hit Enter, Excel does this:  Recalculates the `IsHyperlink` UDF - cell is not a hyperlink.  Notices that the value of the cell is a URL - converts the cell to a hyperlink.  Does not re-recalculate the UDF until you change something else.  It's the order of those first 2 steps that's important:  when the UDF runs, the cell *isn't* a Hyperlink yet.  I have updated the Formula